# IF ELSE CONDITION IN SQL WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

MY QUERY IS

```
DECLARE @AutoApprove BIT    
    SET @AutoApprove = (
            SELECT AutoApprove
            FROM dbo.CommentBox_Setting
            WHERE UserModuleID = @myModuleID
                AND PortalID = @portalID
                AND CultureCode = @cultureCode
            )
```

From this i will get whether 1 OR 0 (TRUE OR FALSE) furthermore i have

```
   SELECT * FROM ComentBox_Comment
                WHERE UpperModuleID = @UpperModuleID
                    AND ModuleID = @myModuleID
                    AND portalID = @portalID
                    AND cultureCode = @cultureCode
                    AND //Here i need to check condition
```

**`(IF(@AutoApprove=0){ THEN isapprove=1}else {do not check})`**

**Note here isapprove is table filedName**

I know ,i can do this with long query i need short and easy way.
Help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
AND CASE WHEN @AutoApprove=0 THEN isapprove ELSE 1 END = 1
```

This will check `isapprove = 1` if `@AutoApprove = 0`, or `1=1(ignore)` otherwise.

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Why '= 1' is used at the end? I mean why we need that part!